# Bivariate normal distribution with $|\rho|=1$

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, bivariate

I have deduced the bivariate normal density function. However am unaware of what happens when the correlation coefficient $\rho$ tends to 1  and -1?

Answer (score 8):

A simple-minded (that is, non-measure-theoretic) version of the answer is as follows.

If random variables $X$ and $Y$ are such 
that

- *every* point $(x,y)$ in a *region* $\mathcal A$
  of the plane is a possible realization of $(X,Y)$
- The *area* of $\mathcal A$ is greater than $0$

and

- $P\{(X,Y) \in \mathcal A\} = 1$

then $X$ and $Y$ are said to be *jointly continuous* random
variables, and their probabilistic behavior can be determined
from their *joint density function* $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ whose *support*
is $\mathcal A$. Note that $X$ and $Y$ are also (marginally) continuous
random variables.

> If $(X,Y)$ have a *bivariate* normal distribution, then they
>   are marginally normal random variables too. In particular,
>   $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables.

**But** $X$
and $Y$ are *jointly continuous* (and thus enjoy the 
bivariate normal joint
density function that you have found or been told about) 
**only** if their (Pearson)
correlation coefficient $\rho \in (-1,1)$. When $\rho = \pm 1$,
$X$ and $Y$ are *not* jointly continuous and they don't have
a joint *density* function. They do, however, continue to
enjoy the properties stated in the highlighted paragraph above.
that is, they are still said to have a bivariate normal
*distribution* (even though they don't have the bivariate
normal *density*), and they are individually normal random
variables (and hence continuous).  Note that in this case,
*all* realizations of $(X,Y)$ lie on the straight line 
$$y = \mu_Y + \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(x-\mu_X)$$
passing through $(\mu_X,\mu_Y)$. Note that the straight line has 
*zero* area.  Since $Y = \mu_Y + \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(X-\mu_X)$,
any questions about the probabilistic behavior of $(X,Y)$ 
can be translated into a question about the probabilistic
behavior of $X$ alone and answered based on the knowledge
that $X \sim N(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$. Since it is also
true that $X = \mu_X + \frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}(Y-\mu_Y)$,
contrary-minded folks might prefer to translate the question
about $(X,Y)$ that has been asked into a question
about the probabilistic behavior of $Y$ alone and answer it
based on the knowledge that $Y \sim N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$

Comment: In measure theoretic terms, when $\rho=\pm 1$, there is a density but only with respect to a measure on the subspace $\{x=\pm y\}$.

Comment: @Xi'an As I said, I didn't want to get into the measure-theoretic version and especially since the OP is asking what happens to the joint density as $\rho$ _tends_ to $+1$ or $-1$ which gets into _limits_ etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Pearson product moment correlation coefficient is a measure of linear dependence. At its extremes, one of the random variables is a linear function of the other with probability one and so there is no randomness.

Comment: How exactly does "the line" manage to "describe" a joint distribution?

Comment: @whuber The distribution is concentrated on it, there is nothing random. Is that wrong?

Comment: It's incomplete, because the distribution is not uniform on that line.

Comment: @whuber I see what you mean, I didn't mean to imply that. Thank you.

Comment: "... the distribution is not uniform on that line." and indeed, since the line is of unbounded length, _no_ distribution can be uniform on that line.